# How to convert array's numeral index into associative array

Tags: php, html, arrays

Currently I'm struggling with posting dynamic form. I'm using simple post, but if there's any method to get data from whole table I would like to know.

So, that's the HTML table:

```
    <form id="importForm" method="post" action="/modules/import/test.php">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped table-sm">
        <thead class="bg-dark thwhite thead-dark">
            <td><small>First name</small></td>
            <td><small>Last name</small></td>
            <td><small>Start date</small></td>
            <td><small>Location</small></td>
            <td><small>Job title</small></td>
            <td><small>Department</small></td>
            <td><small>Manager</small></td>
            <td><small>Hardware</small></td>
            <td><small>Remarks</small></td>

        </thead>

    <?php
    $i = 1;
    foreach($values as $row){ 

        <tr>
        <td style="display:none">
        <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $$i++ ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
        <small><?php echo $row[0] ?></small>
        <input type="hidden" name="firstname[]" value="<?php echo $row[0] ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
        <small><?php echo $row[1] ?></small>
        <input type="hidden" name="lastname[]" value="<?php echo $row[1] ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
        <small><?php echo $row[3] ?></small>
        <input type="hidden" name="startdate[]" value="<?php echo $row[3] ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
        <small><?php echo $row[2] ?></small>
        <input type="hidden" name="location[]" value="<?php echo $row[2] ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
        <small><?php echo $row[4] ?></small>
        <input type="hidden" name="jobtitle[]" value="<?php echo $row[4] ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
        <small><?php echo $row[5] ?></small>
        <input type="hidden" name="department[]" value="<?php echo $row[5] ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
        <small><?php echo $row[6] ?></small>
        <input type="hidden" name="manager[]" value="<?php echo $row[6] ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
        <small><?php echo $row[11] ?></small>
        <input type="hidden" name="hardware[]" value="<?php echo $row[11] ?>">
        </td>
        <td>
        <small><?php echo $row[15] ?></small>
        <input type="hidden" name="remarks[]" value="<?php echo $row[15] ?>">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php }

} ?>
</table>
<div class="w100 tleft">
<button id="importList" class="inline">Import</button>
</div>
</form>
```

And `print_r($_POST)` in **test.php** file looks like this:

```
Array ( 
    [id] => Array ( 
        [0] => 
        [1] => 1 
        [2] => 2 
        [3] => 3 
    ) 
    [firstname] => Array ( 
        [0] => Michael 
        [1] => Dwight 
        [2] => Jim 
        [3] => Andrew 
    ) 
    [lastname] => Array ( 
        [0] => Scott 
        [1] => Schrute 
        [2] => Halpert 
        [3] => Bernard 
    ) 
    [startdate] => Array ( 
        [0] => 1-7-2020 
        [1] => 1-7-2020 
        [2] => 1-7-2020 
        [3] => 1-7-2020 
    ) 
    [location] => Array ( 
        [0] => Scranton office 
        [1] => Scranton office 
        [2] => Scranton office 
        [3] => Scranton office 
    ) 
    [jobtitle] => Array ( 
        [0] => Regional manager 
        [1] => Assistant to the regional manager 
        [2] => Salesman 
        [3] => Salesman 
    ) 
    [department] => Array ( 
        [0] => Management 
        [1] => Sales 
        [2] => Sales 
        [3] => Sales 
    ) 
    [manager] => Array ( 
        [0] => David Wallace 
        [1] => Michael Scott 
        [2] => Michael Scott
        [3] => Michael Scott 
    ) 
    [hardware] => Array ( 
        [0] => Laptop, laptop bag, desk phone 
        [1] => None 
        [2] => None 
        [3] => None 
    ) 
    [remarks] => Array ( 
        [0] => 
        [1] => 
        [2] => 
        [3] => 
    ) 
)
```

output of `foreach ($_POST as $row){ echo $row; }` is not working, I need to echo `$row[1]` and then I've got full row, but I have not control on field like `firstname` or others.

I want to convert this to have possibility to do it like this echo `$row['firstname']` and then `foreach` loop will return all first names.

Comment: I don't think you need to convert anything ? You have the values: foreach ($_POST['firstname'] as $firstname){ echo $firstname; } ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the names of the inputs to the following format:

```
name="person[$i][firstname]"
name="person[$i][lastname]"
...
```

The `$_POST` will then look like:

```
Array(
    [person] => Array( 
        [0] => Array(
            [firstname] => "Foo"
            [lastname]  => "Bar"
            ...
        )
        [1] => Array(
            [firstname] => "Foo2"
            [lastname]  => "Bar2"
            ...
        )
        ...
)
```

You will now be able to loop through the values like this:

```
foreach ($_POST['person'] as $row) {
    echo $row['firstname'];
    echo $row['lastname'];
    ...
}
```

**Note:** I'm not sure how you're using the `$i` variable though, since this: `$$i++` looks odd and might cause issues. I would have set `$i = 0` before the loop and then have a `$i++` as the last item before the closing `}` for the loop.